# How do I address performance issue in this measure calculation?

Tags: dax

```
 Amount (ex mgmt) = 
 IF(
     OR(
         SELECTEDVALUE(IMSEmployeeTimesheet[OriginalCostCentre]) = "1000-92-00", 
         SELECTEDVALUE(IMSEmployeeTimesheet[OriginalCostCentre]) = "1000-09-00"
        ) 
        && 
        NOT(USERPRINCIPALNAME()) IN {"c.hall@abc.com", "s.goss@abc.com", "n.cockroft@abc.com"},
     BLANK(),
     SUMX(IMSEmployeeTimesheet, IMSEmployeeTimesheet[Amount])
 )
```

The above measure is causing performance issues.

> More details: Resource Governing: This query uses more memory than the configured limit. The query — or calculations referenced by it — might be too memory-intensive to run. Either simplify the query or its calculations, or if using Power BI Premium, you may reach out to your capacity administrator to see if they can increase the per-query memory limit. More details: consumed memory 1331 MB, memory limit 1331 MB. Learn more, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2159752.
> Activity ID: 4c980721-99e3-4543-99fb-0b7db9cd9f7d
> Correlation ID: e653bb76-ea95-b019-0e91-97893c535225
> Request ID: 3c57fbc4-f3ac-4f84-9518-20d362d88df1
> Time: Thu Jun 15 2023 11:07:42 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)
> Service version: 13.0.20866.74
> Client version: 2306.1.14294-train
> Cluster URI: https://wabi-australia-southeast-redirect.analysis.windows.net/

I am trying to hide management salaries without affecting the total from teams using the dashboard. Only a handful of people are allowed to view the salaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would split this into two:

```
Amount (ex mgmt) = 
 CALCULATE( SUM(IMSEmployeeTimesheet[Amount]),
    NOT(IMSEmployeeTimesheet[OriginalCostCentre] IN {"1000-92-00","1000-09-00"}))

Amount (mgmt only) = IF( 
   USERPRINCIPALNAME() IN {"c.hall@abc.com", "s.goss@abc.com", "n.cockroft@abc.com"},
   CALCULATE( SUM(IMSEmployeeTimesheet[Amount]),
        IMSEmployeeTimesheet[OriginalCostCentre] IN {"1000-92-00","1000-09-00"}),BLANK())
```

Then you can create a total which is the sum of both. But remember the salaries are still in the model and visible to everyone, if you give the users access to edit the powerbi report. To have this controlled you would need some sort of Row Level Security rule.